# Add centered <hr/>-like line to the middle of a text

Tags: html, css, line

I want to have a responsive UI, which a < hr > line is between 2 text:

```
test ----------------------- test
```

I tried:

```html
test<hr style="display:inline;"/>test
```

but it becomes a vertical line, and I don't want to use table like it:

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td style="width:100%;"><hr/></td>
    <td>test</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

is there any simpler way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use flexbox [easy method]

```css
.main {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.line {
  flex-grow: 1;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  margin: 5px
}
```

```html
<p class="main">
  <span>Text1</span>
  <span class="line"></span>
  <span>Text2</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `<hr>` isn't actually being vertical, it's just so narrow that you only see it's borders, so it *looks* like a vertical line.

Anyway, you can create a line yourself, something like this;

```css
span { background: #000; display: inline-block; height: 1px; width: 100px; vertical-align: middle; }
```

```html
text <span></span> other text
```

Comment: the line needs to be responsive?

Comment: ah, didn't read that, if that's the case @Lucifers answer is the way to go (with flexbox).

Answer (score 0):

Use `flexbox`

```css
.wrap{
display:flex;
}
hr {
  width:95%
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <span>test</span>
  <hr/>
 <span>test</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can consider background like this:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #000) center/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.box span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 2px;
}

.box span:last-child {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>text</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box" style="width:250px;">
  <span>text</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box" style="width:350px;">
  <span>text</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

And with flexbox:

```css
.box {
  display: inline-flex;
  justify-content:space-between;
  width: 200px;
  background: linear-gradient(#000, #000) center/100% 1px no-repeat;
}

.box span {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 0 2px;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <span>text</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box" style="width:250px;">
  <span>text</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
<br>
<div class="box" style="width:350px;">
  <span>text</span>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example by using flexboxes.

```css
.myClass {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.myClass > div {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.myClass > div.grow {
  flex: 1 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class='myClass'>
  <div>test</div>
  <div class='grow'><hr/></div>
  <div>test</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

> Please Try this CODE

```css
.width { width:100%; }
.border {
 border: none;
 border:1px dashed #000;
 width: 100%;
 display:inline-block;
 vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<table>
 <tr>
     <td>Test</td>
        <td class="width"><hr class="border"></td>
        <td> Test </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score -2):

```html
test<hr style="display:inline-block;width:90%;"/>test
```

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged. Please say something about why this works and/or how this is different from the OP code.